# Sliding up Panel android failed to build

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm trying to create a sliding up panel
I have download umano sliding up panel from nuget.
Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--suppress ALL -->
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
     xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="main"/>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

I'm putting Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error parsing XML: unbound prefix 
How can i fix this?

Comment: are you sure, the view you are using can work as container for other layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't add `android` xml namespace to your SlidingUpPanelLayout. Add this to your SlidingUpPanelLayout :

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```